# Why does binary_crossentropy loss not match between fitting/evaluation and manual check?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I train or evaluate with `binary_crossentropy` I'm getting huge values, but when I put the results through manually it looks normal.  What am I doing wrong? I think `binary_crossentropy` can't exceed about 15.5 in any case.

```
test_in, test_out1 = makeTestData()
test_out2 = np.zeros((1000,1))
model.compile(..., loss=['mean_squared_error', 'binary_crossentropy'], loss_weights=[1.0, 0.001])

model.evaluate(test_in,[test_out1, test_out2])
# Result: [0.3238, 0.106, 217.815]

pred = model.predict(test_in)
# np.max(pred[1]) = 1.0, np.min(pred[1]) = 0.0019
K.mean(tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(test_out2, pred[1]))
# Result: 13.31
```

217.8 loss in evaluation (and training, not shown), but only 13.3 when run manually through.

Comment: What's `makeTestData()` ? What's the architecture of your network? Do you have multiple outputs?

Comment: My actual thing has a lot of complexity that I don't think is relevant.  It's also on a system isolated from the internet, so I can't just paste it in.  makeTestData() is imaginary, just to set up the problem.  The real question is, generically, how can I get wildly different losses in these cases?  Yes, it has multiple outputs.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example

Comment: I really just want to know under what circumstances running the prediction through the loss function can yield wildly different results than evaluation.  I have no code on an internet connected machine that I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to determine what might be the issue here with such a minimal example. I have 2 theories:

1. Your data is not the same when running manually vs not manually. Something is amiss here, and it's blowing up because of that.
2. Your evaluation mode is different when running 'manually', vs not manually, and you've fallen into this very [particular edgecase](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L5025-L5026):

```
  if (not isinstance(output, (ops.EagerTensor, variables_module.Variable)) and
      output.op.type == 'Sigmoid') and not hasattr(output, '_keras_history'):
    # When sigmoid activation function is used for output operation, we
    # use logits from the sigmoid function directly to compute loss in order
    # to prevent collapsing zero when training.
    # ... computes using logits

  # ... computes manually with clipping
```

If the latter looks to be true, try passing the logits directly without doing a sigmoid to see if you can end up with consistent values. In addition, you might try passing in the [`from_logits=True` flag](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/binary_crossentropy#args)

Comment: I think you're onto something with #2.  I haven't butchered my model to remove the sigmoid, but the more I think about it, if the eval uses logits under the hood, I think it could have much bigger losses in some cases since a logit could be quite large in magnitude and still map down to 1.0, for example.  The code not using logits relies on an epsilon factor to protect the log, which caps loss at 15-16 or so, while I think the logit based loss could be nearly unbounded.  I need to experiment a bit more here.

Comment: You can also throw on an identity op at the end of your model to standardize behavior. This current conditional is super brittle

Comment: FYI, a quick experiment shows what can happen here.  Compare tf.losses.binary_crossentropy([0.],[tf.sigmoid(x)]) to tf.losses.binary_crossentropy([0.],[x],from_logits=True).  For small x, the answers are very close.  For large x the former caps out at around 15.5 and the latter keeps growing.  For x of 225, the loss is 225, for example.